# Understanding the behavior of JavaScript call function

Tags: javascript, function

Let I have a simple code

```
{
  let i = 10;
  function outer() {
    let j = 20;
    console.log(i, j);
  }
  let inner = outer();
}
```

And the output is

```
10 20
```

which is obvious. But I thought I only stored the function value in inner, but never called it. Then why is it logging the output to the console?

Comment: You called the function let inner = outer();

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want to know. You call the function right there in your code. `inner` is equal to the return value of your `outer` function: `undefined`. If you want to copy the reference to your function, you’d use `let inner = outer;` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I almost forgot that bracket part.

Answer (score 1):

let inner = outer() => executes the function

let inner = outer => save the function to inner

As you can see the difference is the parentheses.

When you use parentheses, you are saying execute this function.

Answer (score 1):

The outmost braces just indicate they make a "code block", not a function body.

In `outer` function, it initializes a local variable 'j' and refer to a external variable `i`. And you called the function with `let inner = outer()`.